# Подключение к БД со значениями из ini файла

Tags: php, база-данных, ini

php:

```
private $mysqli;

    function baseConnect()
    {
        $db_info = parse_ini_file("../conf/db.ini");
        $host = $db_info['host'];
        $user = $db_info['user'];
        $pass = $db_info['pass'];
        $base = $db_info['base'];
        $this->mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $base);
    }
```

на такую команду:

```
$select = $this->mysqli->query($db);
```

ругается так:

```
Call to a member function query() on null
```

Первая мысль - пустые строки, строки не пустые, подозрения на

```
$this->mysqli =
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых проверьте вызываете ли вы `baseConnect()` в конструкторе класса, либо его требуется вызвать до обращения к методу `$this->mysqli->query()` . Во-вторых всегда указывайте модификаторы доступа к методам, даже если хотите объявить его `public` - делайте это явно. Вот ссылка на принятые в опенсорс сообществе стандарты написания кода https://www.php-fig.org/psr/